# Prevent onclick jquery function to allow an onclick ajax submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id="1">   
    <form style="height:42px;" lpformnum="1">             
        <h4 class="pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize; width:11%;">
            Title:
        </h4>
        <textarea class="pull-left" style="margin-right:1%;">
            This is a msg 
        </textarea>
         <h4 class="pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize; width:6%;">
             Title 2:
         </h4>
         <input class="pull-left" style="width:8%;  margin-right:1%; " type="text" 
                id="myid" value=""
         />
         <button class="pull-left btn btn-primary" id="update" value="1" type="submit" 
                 style="width:7%; margin-right:1%;" name="credits">Submit</button> 
         <button class="pull-left btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="delete" style="width:6%" 
                 value="" name="credits">Delete</button>                
    </form>
</div>


<script>
    $(".alert").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){             
            var checkValues = $(this).attr('id');
            var checkPost = $(this).children("textarea").text();
            var checkType = $(this).children("span").attr('class');
            var checkName = $(this).children("span").attr('class');
            $.ajax({
                url: '/se/test.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {id:checkValues, posti:checkPost, types:checkType, name:checkName},
                success:function(data){
                    $(this).remove();   // location.reload();
                }
            });             
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code works great, but I need to allow the buttons inside the div.alert to submit the form via ajax on click.

```
<script>
    $('button[id=update]').click(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        var checkValues = $(this).children("#update").val();
        var checkCred = $(this).children("#ucredits").val();
        var checkPost = $(this).children("textarea").text();
        var checkType = $(this).children("i").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_social_cred.php",
            data: { id: checkValues, credits: checkCred, text: checkPost, type: checkType  },
            success:function(result) {
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

However I have tried this many different ways, and either the button doesn't submit the form, or it attempts to submit the form via a standard submission instead of via ajax.

How do I prevent the .alert click function thus allowing the buttons to submit the forms via ajax?

Comment: Tried this? `$('.alert.alert-success').on('click', 'button[id=update]', function() {`

Comment: You want to prevent the `.alert` click event and  allow this event inside your ajax `update_social_cred.php`  ?

Comment: @Scott I have now. Same result. If I change the type to "button" it does nothing, if I leave the type as submit, it attempts to submit the form only not via ajax.

Comment: @John that is the idea, prevent the click event on .alert and allow the button to submit the form via ajax.

Comment: So the button functions but the default form submit is occurring?... then change `function() {` to `function(e) {` (You're missing the event that the prevent default is targeting.)

Comment: U missed function(e){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.alert.alert-success').on('click', 'button[id=update]', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var checkValues = $(this).children("#update").val();
        var checkCred = $(this).children("#ucredits").val();
        var checkPost = $(this).children("textarea").text();
        var checkType = $(this).children("i").text();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "update_social_cred.php",
            data: { id: checkValues, credits: checkCred, text: checkPost, type: checkType  },
            success:function(result) {
            }
        });
    });
```

The difference is the click handler...

`$('.alert.alert-success').on('click', 'button[id=update]', function(e) {`

target the dynamic element, `.alert.alert-success`, then bind an event `.on('click'`, then the item the event is bound to -  `button[id-update]`. Then pass the event itself to the function - `function(e)`

This will target the button click and your `e.preventDefault();` will actually work. the `e` in `e.preventDefault` is the event. You weren't passing it through the function, so the submit button was doing what a submit button does.

Comment: I wish it was so simple, but unfortunately no, its preventing the default submit of the form, but its still not submitting via ajax, and its still not preventing the .alert onclick.

Comment: Oh I missed the click layering issue.. have you tried `e.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: Ragnar Lothbrok wins again. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from jsFiddle : [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eezuuhqu/)

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('.alert').on('click', '#update', function () {
          alert('submit ok');
  });
});
```

Hope that will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `on / off` like this :

**Create a function click alert**

```
function alertClick(){
    $(this).fadeOut(300, function(){
        var checkValues = $(this).attr('id');
        var checkPost = $(this).children("textarea").text();
        var checkType = $(this).children("span").attr('class');
        var checkName = $(this).children("span").attr('class');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/se/test.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {id:checkValues, posti:checkPost, types:checkType, name:checkName},
            success:function(data){
                $(this).remove();   // location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**Bind your click event inside your button id update Ajax**

```
$('button[id=update]').on('click', function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkValues = $(this).children("#update").val();
    var checkCred = $(this).children("#ucredits").val();
    var checkPost = $(this).children("textarea").text();
    var checkType = $(this).children("i").text();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "update_social_cred.php",
        data: { id: checkValues, credits: checkCred, text: checkPost, type: checkType  },
        success:function(result) {
            $(".alert").on('click', alertClick); // Bind click event
        }
    });
});
```

And if you need to unbind the event later on another action you can use this :

```
$(".alert").off('click');
```

And rebind with this :

```
$(".alert").on('click', alertClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#divId #buttonId").on({
    click: function() {
    // your code here
  }
})
```